# How to provide feedback when dismissing topic request?

Tags: support, documentation

There is no way to provide feedback to the topic requester when dismissing spurious or otherwise unnecessary topic requests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can leave a comment on the specific request, if you feel like it. This is a privilege that requires 50 reputation, just like commenting on the Q&A site.

Comment: If this is the proposed way to do it, that's what I'll do.

Comment: Although it would be easier if a one liner pop-up box appeared like it does for the duplicate topic choice.

Comment: @cb4 the comment section is a comment section because is optional. The "official" reason is given in the next dialog box.

Comment: How do I do this? There's no comment text box, button, or link. I have far more than 50 reputation; do I need 50 reputation specifically from the documentation site?

Comment: Also, I read that I was able to click one of 3 options such as "not necessary" or "duplicate" when dismissing a request, but I was provided with no such option, leaving whoever submitted the request in the dark.

Comment: @ekolis there's a "add comment" in this [proposed changes](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/68690), there is another in this [topic request](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/topic-requests/4873). The improvement request don't have comment, since it's either dismissed or acted upon.

Comment: @ekolis I see the modal when I clicked "dismiss" in this [topic request](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/git/topic-requests/4343)

Comment: But I want to explain *why* I'm dismissing it; for instance someone suggested an article in Windows 10 about how to create a hello world app. I dismissed it because it seemed irrelevant (shouldn't that go into a programming language topic?) but I had no way to specify that it was irrelevant, let alone why I thought it was irrelevant.

Comment: @ekolis you can comment in the request itself and dismiss it... I'm not sure why you want more than that?

Comment: Nope, there was no option such as that for me. Ah, it looks like it wasn't a topic request; it was a request for improvement of an existing topic (orange, not blue).