# In documentation someone should have to provide a reason for dismissing a request for a topic improvement

Tags: feature-request, documentation

When the community requests improvements. I can dismiss them without providing a reason.

In the image below there are three requests.

1. I think doesn't make any sense
2. I think has been handled
3. I think has been handled

[image: Improvements requested by the community]

I think we should have to provide a reason for the dismissal so that a reviewer can try to determine whether we were right to dismiss.

(NB I can't tell if this is a duplicate of [How to provide feedback when dismissing topic request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328818/how-to-provide-feedback-when-dismissing-topic-request))

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate; topic requests seem to be distinct from improvement requests.